# Grunt.js/Grunt-contrib-watch packaged with Yeoman does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, livereload, grunt-contrib-watch

I recently installed Yeoman and am finding that the included livereload feature (provided by grunt-watch-contrib) does not work. In fact, nothing short of restarting the Node server altogether actually allows me to see my SCSS changes in the browser. I don't even know where to begin looking in order to fix this, as whatever errors are occurring are silent ones.

What could I be doing wrong? Isn't this just supposed to work "right out of the box"?

I'm using OS X Mavericks.

Here is the output of grunt watch --verbose:

```
Initializing
Command-line options: --verbose

Reading "gruntfile.js" Gruntfile...OK

Registering Gruntfile tasks.

Registering "grunt-contrib-compass" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /Users/ExNihil/newMeanTestApp/node_modules/grunt-contrib-compass/package.json...OK
Parsing /Users/ExNihil/newMeanTestApp/node_modules/grunt-contrib-compass/package.json...OK
Loading "compass.js" tasks...OK
+ compass

Registering "grunt-contrib-watch" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /Users/ExNihil/newMeanTestApp/node_modules/grunt-contrib-watch/package.json...OK
Parsing /Users/ExNihil/newMeanTestApp/node_modules/grunt-contrib-watch/package.json...OK
Loading "watch.js" tasks...OK
+ watch

Registering "grunt-contrib-jshint" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /Users/ExNihil/newMeanTestApp/node_modules/grunt-contrib-jshint/package.json...OK
Parsing /Users/ExNihil/newMeanTestApp/node_modules/grunt-contrib-jshint/package.json...OK
Loading "jshint.js" tasks...OK
+ jshint

Registering "grunt-nodemon" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /Users/ExNihil/newMeanTestApp/node_modules/grunt-nodemon/package.json...OK
Parsing /Users/ExNihil/newMeanTestApp/node_modules/grunt-nodemon/package.json...OK
Loading "nodemon.js" tasks...OK
+ nodemon

Registering "grunt-concurrent" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /Users/ExNihil/newMeanTestApp/node_modules/grunt-concurrent/package.json...OK
Parsing /Users/ExNihil/newMeanTestApp/node_modules/grunt-concurrent/package.json...OK
Loading "concurrent.js" tasks...OK
+ concurrent

Registering "grunt-mocha-test" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /Users/ExNihil/newMeanTestApp/node_modules/grunt-mocha-test/package.json...OK
Parsing /Users/ExNihil/newMeanTestApp/node_modules/grunt-mocha-test/package.json...OK
Loading "mocha.js" tasks...OK
+ mochaTest
Reading package.json...OK
Parsing package.json...OK
Initializing config...OK

Registering "grunt-contrib-watch" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /Users/ExNihil/newMeanTestApp/node_modules/grunt-contrib-watch/package.json...OK
Parsing /Users/ExNihil/newMeanTestApp/node_modules/grunt-contrib-watch/package.json...OK
Loading "watch.js" tasks...OK
+ watch

Registering "grunt-contrib-jshint" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /Users/ExNihil/newMeanTestApp/node_modules/grunt-contrib-jshint/package.json...OK
Parsing /Users/ExNihil/newMeanTestApp/node_modules/grunt-contrib-jshint/package.json...OK
Loading "jshint.js" tasks...OK
+ jshint

Registering "grunt-mocha-test" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /Users/ExNihil/newMeanTestApp/node_modules/grunt-mocha-test/package.json...OK
Parsing /Users/ExNihil/newMeanTestApp/node_modules/grunt-mocha-test/package.json...OK
Loading "mocha.js" tasks...OK
+ mochaTest

Registering "grunt-nodemon" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /Users/ExNihil/newMeanTestApp/node_modules/grunt-nodemon/package.json...OK
Parsing /Users/ExNihil/newMeanTestApp/node_modules/grunt-nodemon/package.json...OK
Loading "nodemon.js" tasks...OK
+ nodemon

Registering "grunt-concurrent" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /Users/ExNihil/newMeanTestApp/node_modules/grunt-concurrent/package.json...OK
Parsing /Users/ExNihil/newMeanTestApp/node_modules/grunt-concurrent/package.json...OK
Loading "concurrent.js" tasks...OK
+ concurrent
Loading "gruntfile.js" tasks...OK
+ default, test

Running tasks: watch

Running "watch" task
Waiting...Verifying property watch exists in config...OK
Verifying property watch.jade.files exists in config...OK
Verifying property watch.js.files exists in config...OK
Verifying property watch.html.files exists in config...OK
Verifying property watch.css.files exists in config...OK
Live reload server started on port: 35729
Watching app/views for changes.
Watching app/views/includes for changes.
Watching app/views/layouts for changes.
Watching app/views/404.jade for changes.
Watching app/views/500.jade for changes.
Watching app/views/index.jade for changes.
Watching app/views/includes/foot.jade for changes.
Watching app/views/includes/head.jade for changes.
Watching app/views/layouts/default.jade for changes.
Watching public/js for changes.
Watching public/js/controllers for changes.
Watching public/js/services for changes.
Watching public/js/app.js for changes.
Watching public/js/config.js for changes.
Watching public/js/directives.js for changes.
Watching public/js/filters.js for changes.
Watching public/js/init.js for changes.
Watching public/js/controllers/index.js for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.min.js for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.min.js for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/demo/demo.js for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/gruntFile.js for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/demo for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/test for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/event/event.js for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/event/demo for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/event/test for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/event/test/eventSpec.js for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/format/format.js for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/format/demo for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/format/test for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/format/test/formatSpec.js for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/highlight/highlight.js for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/highlight/demo for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/highlight/test for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/highlight/test/highlightSpec.js for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/ie-shiv/ie-shiv.js for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/indeterminate/indeterminate.js for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/indeterminate/demo for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/indeterminate/test for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/indeterminate/test/indeterminateSpec.js for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/inflector/inflector.js for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/inflector/demo for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/inflector/test for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/inflector/test/inflectorSpec.js for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/jq/jq.js for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/jq/demo for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/jq/test for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/jq/test/jqSpec.js for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/keypress/keypress.js for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/keypress/demo for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/keypress/test for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/keypress/test/keydownSpec.js for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/keypress/test/keypressSpec.js for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/keypress/test/keyupSpec.js for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/mask/mask.js for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/mask/demo for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/mask/test for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/mask/test/maskSpec.js for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/reset/reset.js for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/reset/demo for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/reset/stylesheets for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/reset/test for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/reset/test/resetSpec.js for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/route/route.js for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/route/demo for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/route/test for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/route/test/routeSpec.js for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/scrollfix/scrollfix.js for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/scrollfix/demo for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/scrollfix/test for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/scrollfix/test/scrollfixSpec.js for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/showhide/showhide.js for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/showhide/demo for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/showhide/test for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/showhide/test/showhideSpec.js for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/unique/test/uniqueSpec.js for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/unique/unique.js for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/unique/demo for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/unique/test for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/utils.js for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/event for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/format for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/highlight for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/ie-shiv for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/indeterminate for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/inflector for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/jq for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/keypress for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/mask for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/reset for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/route for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/scrollfix for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/showhide for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/unique for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/validate for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/validate/test/validateSpec.js for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/validate/validate.js for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/validate/demo for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/modules/validate/test for changes.
Watching app/components/angular-ui-utils/test/karma.conf.js for changes.
Watching app/components/angular/angular.js for changes.
Watching app/components/angular/angular.min.js for changes.
Watching app/components/jquery/jquery-migrate.js for changes.
Watching app/components/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js for changes.
Watching app/components/jquery/jquery.js for changes.
Watching app/components/jquery/jquery.min.js for changes.
Watching app/components/json3/lib/json3.js for changes.
Watching app/components/json3/lib/json3.min.js for changes.
Watching app/components/sass-bootstrap/Gruntfile.js for changes.
Watching app/components/sass-bootstrap/_includes for changes.
Watching app/components/sass-bootstrap/_layouts for changes.
Watching app/components/sass-bootstrap/dist for changes.
Watching app/components/sass-bootstrap/docs-assets for changes.
Watching app/components/sass-bootstrap/examples for changes.
Watching app/components/sass-bootstrap/fonts for changes.
Watching app/components/sass-bootstrap/js for changes.
Watching app/components/sass-bootstrap/lib for changes.
Watching app/components/sass-bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js for changes.
Watching app/components/sass-bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js for changes.
Watching app/components/sass-bootstrap/docs-assets/js/application.js for changes.
Watching app/components/sass-bootstrap/docs-assets/js/customizer.js for changes.
Watching app/components/sass-bootstrap/docs-assets/js/filesaver.js for changes.
Watching app/components/sass-bootstrap/docs-assets/js/holder.js for changes.
Watching app/components/sass-bootstrap/docs-assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js for changes.
Watching app/components/sass-bootstrap/docs-assets/js/jszip.js for changes.
Watching app/components/sass-bootstrap/docs-assets/js/less.js for changes.
Watching app/components/sass-bootstrap/docs-assets/js/raw-files.js for changes.
Watching app/components/sass-bootstrap/docs-assets/js/uglify.js for changes.
Watching app/components/sass-bootstrap/examples/offcanvas/offcanvas.js for changes.
Watching app/components/sass-bootstrap/js/affix.js for changes.
Watching app/components/sass-bootstrap/js/tests for changes.
Watching app/components/sass-bootstrap/js/alert.js for changes.
Watching app/components/sass-bootstrap/js/button.js for changes.
Watching app/components/sass-bootstrap/js/carousel.js for changes.
Watching app/components/sass-bootstrap/js/collapse.js for changes.
Watching app/components/sass-bootstrap/js/dropdown.js for changes.
Watching app/components/sass-bootstrap/js/modal.js for changes.
Watching app/components/sass-bootstrap/js/popover.js for changes.
Watching app/components/sass-bootstrap/js/scrollspy.js for changes.
Watching app/components/sass-bootstrap/js/tab.js for changes.
Watching app/components/sass-bootstrap/js/tooltip.js for changes.
Watching app/components/sass-bootstrap/js/transition.js for changes.
Watching app/components/sass-bootstrap/js/tests/unit/affix.js for changes.
Watching app/components/sass-bootstrap/js/tests/unit/alert.js for changes.
Watching app/components/sass-bootstrap/js/tests/unit/button.js for changes.
Watching app/components/sass-bootstrap/js/tests/unit/carousel.js for changes.
Watching app/components/sass-bootstrap/js/tests/unit/collapse.js for changes.
Watching app/components/sass-bootstrap/js/tests/unit/dropdown.js for changes.
Watching app/components/sass-bootstrap/js/tests/unit/modal.js for changes.
Watching app/components/sass-bootstrap/js/tests/unit/phantom.js for changes.
Watching app/components/sass-bootstrap/js/tests/unit/popover.js for changes.
Watching app/components/sass-bootstrap/js/tests/unit/scrollspy.js for changes.
Watching app/components/sass-bootstrap/js/tests/unit/tab.js for changes.
Watching app/components/sass-bootstrap/js/tests/unit/tooltip.js for changes.
Watching app/components/sass-bootstrap/js/tests/unit/transition.js for changes.
Watching app/components/sass-bootstrap/js/tests/vendor/jquery.js for changes.
Watching app/components/sass-bootstrap/js/tests/vendor/qunit.js for changes.
Watching app/controllers/index.js for changes.
Watching public/views for changes.
Watching public/views/index.html for changes.
```

Comment: Are you using windows? https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/issues/63

Comment: Ah, ok. Can you tell us what the output of `grunt watch --verbose` is?

Comment: I am running that fine on OS X Mavericks. You should include your grunt verbose output.

Comment: No problem. See the original post.